# How do you get the top value of newData in Firebase Realtime Database rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

New to firebase rules. I may be thinking about this all wrong, but anyway, I am trying to create a rule that makes sure that the newData being written to the database does not exist under the node it is being written. To write to the database I am using this code:

```
self.reference?.child("users").child(userid).setValue(data) {
            (error, result) in
            if (error != nil) {
                completion(true, error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                completion(false, "")
            }
        }
```

Here is where I'd like to create the rule:

```
    {
  "rules": {
        ".read": false,
      "users": {
        ".write": //allow write if the newData's keyBasedOnAuthID is not under students already
          "$student_id": {
                //more rules...
            }
      },
```

My incoming newData looks something like this:

```
{ keyBasedOnAuthID {
 uid: auth.uid 
 name: xxxx
 other:{
  key: xxx
  key: xxx
  }
} }
```

I am writing this data to a node named 'users,' so the final path would be root.child('users').child(newData). The rule I would like to make would prevent users from writing duplicate data to the 'users' node. So I want to get the keyBasedOnAuthID value from the newData and check that it does not already exist.

Is this possible? I've tried many different ways to retrieve the keyBasedOnAuthID from the newData snapshot, but none have worked. Maybe I need a different approach? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It might be more clear if you edit the question to show the **full** code that adds data, and explain more clearly the circumstances where you want to accept the new data being written.

Comment: @DougStevenson is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure which language your using.

However, `setValue` doesn't create duplicates: either creates or updates data for the given  path.

So, if you don't want to **update** existing data, you need to check for existence before calling your `setValue` method in your application code.